# django user fields shown empty in template

Tags: django, django-templates

cannot access fields in templates

model.py:

```
class DSS(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='عنوان')
    usr = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', verbose_name='کاربر')
```

view.py:

```
def state(request):
    result = DSS.objects.values('usr').order_by('usr').annotate(count=Count('usr'))
    context = {'result': result,}
    return render(request, 'state.html', context)
```

my template:

```
 <tr>
    <td>{{ item.usr }}{{ item.usr.get_username}}{{ item.usr.username}}{{ item.usr.get_full_name}}</td>
    <td>{% with item.usr.get_username as usrnm %}
        {{ item.usr.get_full_name|default:usrnm }}
        {% endwith %}</td>
    <td>{{ item.usr.first_name }} {{ item.usr.lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.owner.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.count }}</td>
</tr>
```

{{ item.count }} work well and {{ item.usr }} just show user id, but I need to display username however none of this tries worked!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [**`values()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values), try to send the actual queryset. And to reduce DB hits, you can use [**`select_related()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). For example:

```
result = DSS.objects.select_related('usr').order_by('usr')
```

Also `.annotate(count=Count('usr'))` will not work properly. It will show 1 for each item of queryset. Instead, try aggregating.

```
def state(request):
    result = DSS.objects.select_related('usr').order_by('usr')
    user_count = result.aggregate(u_count=Count('usr')).get('u_count')
    context = {'result': result, 'user_count': user_count}
    return render(request, 'state.html', context)
```

And render it in template:

```
{{ user_count }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
result = DSS.objects.values('usr').order_by('usr').annotate(count=Count('usr'))
```

Try

```
result = DSS.objects.values('usr', 'usr__username').order_by('usr').annotate(count=Count('usr'))
```

And in html

```
{{ item.usr__username }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `__str__` method in the user model.

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        # use the fields you have in your user model, mine was first_name and last_name
```